# Apple Pie Failure

Tags: dessert

is there a fix for an apple pie where the crust is perfectly baked and tasty but the apples underneath did not cook all the way and are still crunchy and not soft??  I used Fuji apples but could have used many others.  What went wrong?

Comment: I'm not so knowledgeable about apples, but in our book only Granny Smith apples will do for apple pie.

Comment: You should add baked at what temperature and for how long.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is possible that you did not bake the pie long enough.  If your crust is browning too fast, covering it with aluminum foil can help slow the browning so that your filling can cook completely.  I would also suggest using the middle rack in your oven, and avoiding convection.

Comment: We place the pie plate on a foil covered tray, with foil around the sides of the pie. We don't cover the top, and as mentioned the oven rack should be in the middle or a bit higher. The tray should be heavy gauge (we use the bottom part of a broiler pan), not a thin cookie sheet.